# How do I make two Ubuntu machines in vmware to ping each other?

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, vmware, ping

Do I need to install special tools for that, or is it all just networking settings ? I've seen people do this in windows machines on vmware but never with ubuntu

Both ubuntu machines have this configuration, it's basically default i did not edit it:

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRqWd.png)

Comment: What network configuration are you using for your VMs?

Comment: Are the VM's networking configured as `NAT` or `Bridged` or something else?

Comment: Hi i edited with the picture of the network configuration please check it out, i did not edit this and these configs apply to both machines. also is making ubuntu machines communicate solely relies on your ability to ping from one to the next using the terminal ? or are there other ways to communicate between them ?

Comment: I saw this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEbF73JyRVc basically he uses one linux and one windows, but what i wish to achieve is the same. just with two ubuntus. I don't know how to ascertain what address to manually feed in the settings of each machine, before pinging.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox/119743) is probably similar to your situation but using VirtualBox.

I would suggest to use bridged mode for networking which, exposes the VM to your internal network.
But this might require a DHCP server for IP assignment or in-case your current network is configured using Static IP then probably assign different IP addresses for those VM's.

Once configured you can try and ping the machines, from host and between guests to verify the network is functional.

If you don't want to expose your VM's to the network you can still have a look at the linked, answer for more information about different networking configurations.(Both VMware and VirtualBox have very similar configurations for Networking)

**Note:** In-case you are running those VM's in a corporate environment then, I would suggest to contact your IT team for configuring those VM's networking.